# quotient of an object 2

Tags: category-theory, epimorphisms

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247308/quotient-of-an-object) I've asked what is a quotient of an object and the answer was that it is an equivalence class of epis.

But [here](http://www.math.muni.cz/%7Erosicky/papers/neum.ps) on the first page they claim that regular quotient is an **co**equalizer of 2 morphisms. I do not follow why this **co**equalizer should be **epi**.

Comment: Without compiling the postscript, are you sure the paper didn't mean coequaliser?

Comment: @user2628206 A mouseslip, you are right. So what is the next step to answer my question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your question is: If $c\colon B\to C$ is the coequalizer of the pair $f,g\colon A\to B$, why is $c$ an epimorphism?

To show that $c$ is an epimorphism, suppose $p,q\colon C\to D$ are two arrows such that $p\circ c = q\circ c$. We need to show that $p = q$.

Let $h = p\circ c = q\circ c\colon B\to D$. Since $c$ coequalizes $f$ and $g$, we have $c\circ f = c\circ g$, so $h\circ f = p\circ c \circ f = p\circ c \circ g = h\circ g$. Thus $h$ coequalizes $f$ and $g$. By the universal property of the coequalizer, there is a unique arrow $h'\colon C\to D$ such that $h'\circ c = h$. By uniqueness, $h' = p = q$.

An arrow is called a *regular epimorphism* if it is a coequalizer for some parallel pair of arrows. Dually, every equalizer is a monomorphism, and an arrow is called a *regular monomorphism* if it is an equalizer for some parallel pair of arrows.

Comment: There is a shorter proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215876/how-to-prove-that-coequalizer-is-a-epimorphism) where I do not understand : By the universal property of $c$, there is a unique $\gamma\colon Z \to A$ such that $\gamma c = \alpha c = \beta c$

Comment: @user122424 But the proof you link to is *exactly* the same argument I gave, just using different variable names...

Comment: Also, it's not meaningfully shorter. If you delete the paragraph break and the explanatory "We need to show that p = q" in my proof, then both proofs are exactly four lines long!

Comment: I understand your proof but I have a difficulty to translate your proof into their : why$\gamma c = \alpha c = \beta c$.

Comment: Their $\alpha$ is my $p$. Their $\beta$ is my $q$. Their $\gamma$ is my $h'$. Their equation $\gamma c = \alpha c = \beta c$ is my $h'\circ c = h$ (since $h = p\circ c = q\circ c$).